# How to check image by reading stream without wiping it

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nancy

I have a function that saves a users profile image to the server when they register.

My Problem: I check the image to ensure its of a valid type for security purposes. But when I do so I seem to wipe the stream and cannot write the image to the server.

How can I check the file for security and not corrupt the stream? The problem occurs in the function `IsValidImage`.

```
private string GetUploadedImage(HttpFile imageFile, long userId, IRootPathProvider pathProvider)
{
    // the following call wipes imageFile.Value or corrupts it
    if (!IsValidImage(imageFile.Value))
        return string.Empty;

    string path = Path.Combine(pathProvider.GetRootPath() + "/abc/", userId + Path.GetExtension(imageFile.Name));
    Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.GetDirectoryName(path));

    using (var fileStream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create))
    {
        imageFile.Value.CopyTo(fileStream);
    }

    return path;
}

private bool IsValidImage(Stream image)
{
    ImageFormat[] ValidFormats = new[] { ImageFormat.Jpeg, ImageFormat.Png };

    try
    {
        // this wipes or corrupts the stream. How can I avoid this?
        using (var img = Image.FromStream(image))
        {
            return ValidFormats.Contains(img.RawFormat);
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you've read from a stream (which IsValidImage does using `Image.FromStream`), you need to "rewind" it to read the data over again.

You can do this by setting the position:

```
using (var fileStream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create))
{
    imageFile.Value.Position= 0;
    imageFile.Value.CopyTo(fileStream);
}
```